# A problem about successive minima of a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: optimization, integer-lattices

**The problem:**

Given $\Lambda$ be a full-rank lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which has $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \; ... < \lambda_n$ as successive minima. There exist $\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2, ..., \textbf{x}_n \in \Lambda$ satisfying $\|\textbf{x}_i\| = \lambda_i \; \forall i$.

Decide whether the matrix $$\textbf{X} = [\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2, ..., \textbf{x}_n]$$ ($\textbf{x}_i$ are its columns) is always a basis of $\Lambda$.

$\text{ }$

*Note:* I believe the answer is ***Not always*** but I've failed to provide a counterexample.

Comment: If you relax $\lambda_1<\cdots<\lambda_n$ to  $\lambda_1\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n$, then I can give you an example for any $n\geq6$.

Comment: In that case, I had an example for every $n \geq 5$. So the question sticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slight modification of the commonly known counterexample for $n=5$.

Let $a=1.00001$ and let $\Lambda$ be the lattice generated by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0&0&a/2\\0&a^2&0&0&a^2/2\\0&0&a^3&0&a^3/2\\0&0&0&a^4&a^4/2\\0&0&0&0&1/2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the successive minima of $\Lambda$ are $1<a<a^2<a^3<a^4$ but the columns of the matrix
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0&0&0\\0&a^2&0&0&0\\0&0&a^3&0&0\\0&0&0&a^4&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
do not form a basis of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Is $n = 5$ the minimal dimension where there are counterexamples?